# Can't find .apk file in the Facebook SDK folder

Tags: android, emulation

I Can't find .apk file in the Facebook SDK folder. i have download the rar folder from here:
[`Link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

**edit:**

```
2. Install the Facebook SDK for Android and the Facebook APK
Download and extract the SDK ZIP file. The resulting folder, facebook-android-sdk-3.5, contains the SDK itself. Note the location of this folder.
The installable APK of the Facebook app is in the bin folder of the SDK, and named FBAndroid-3.5.apk or similar
Secondly, locate the adb tool in the platform-tools directory of your main Android SDK. On OS X, you will have chosen this location when you unzipped the Android SDK. On Windows, the SDK is installed into your home directory, under AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
Assuming you’ve placed the Facebook SDK in your home directory, you use adb to install the APK to the running emulator in OS X like this:
./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk
And on Windows, like this:
adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\bin\FBAndroid-3.5.apk
You should now see the Facebook app in the emulator’s app list or home screen.
```

help me how should i put the fb in my emulator?

Comment: i don't believe you need an apk  its not for your phone. its for your IDE

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/Facebook-11.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the newest Facebook APK for SDK 3.15 is no longer located inside the sdk bin folder (documentation needs updating) but can be found as a separate download off this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

Click on: Facebook APK 10.0